# Display Month Name from Given Date?

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-date-functions

I was written the command for displaying month from Given Date but i got Null value

Example:

```
SELECT strftime('%m',`Exp_Date`) //this is command for fetching value

FROM Expense_item  //this would be a Column name in Table
```

Actually here My table name is Expense_item in that we have column name Exp_Date.and that column having the Data 01-March-2012.

How can i get that Month from that date

Thanks Advance

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat In Java` try to search it in google....

Comment: is there Any Build in fUNCTION FOR THAT ?

Comment: He wants readymade code. And is not interested in putting any efforts it seems. C'mon @Venkat get sporty. Dig it out. Google is your friend.

Comment: What is the datatype of the field Exp_Date?

Answer (score 2):

Just put this block of code to get the month,

```
    String tempDate = "01-March-2012";
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    try {
        new GregorianCalendar().setTime((Date)new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy").parse(tempDate));
        System.out.println(" Month is : "+calendar.MONTH);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column does not seem to have a valid time string value. From the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
A time string can be in any of the following formats:

YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**SimpleDateFormat**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class for the conversion of date format. Do google search for SimpleDateFormat example.